# possibility of passing php into new javascript window

Tags: javascript, php

I have two pages I am working with, I will refer to the first as the Parent and the second as the Child. I am using the following code to open the child window.

```
echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">
<!--

function win1(OrderNum) {
    var focuswindow = window.open(\"OrderInfo.php?OrderNum=\" + OrderNum ,\"Window2\",\"menubar=no,width=700,height=360,toolbar=no\");
    focuswindow.focus();
    }

//-->
</script>";
```

In addition to this generated link

```
echo "<a href=\"javascript:win1(" . $row['OrderNum'] . ")\" onMouseOver=\"self.status='Open A Window'; return true;\"><b>" . $row['OrderNum'] . "</b></a>";
```

My question is this, it is possible to append further information to this Child window by opening a third window? The reason for this is I use a php based telnet command to gather information from some of my devices. I want to be able to put a list of commands in reference to these orders on the Parent window and allow for people to click the commands they need and append it to the Child window so they can then select the whole thing and paste it into a ticketing system.

The reason I am considering the third window is I know php is server side and thus you cannot load the information live by javascript. I was thinking it may be possible to have the third window be opened, php information retrieved, append its information to the Child, then close itself. but I cannot find any references here on SO or Google one something resembling this.

Answer (score 0):

Look into AJAX. You can make connections to your server and get results without opening new windows.